# Matlab - array of matrices

Tags: matlab

I have two matrices A1 and A2, for example A1 = [1 0; 1 1]; and A2 = [0 1; 1 1];

Now I don't want to have them called A1 and A2 since I will have An matrices.

So I wanted something like

A(1) = [1 0; 1 1];
A(2) = [0 1; 1 1];
..
A(n) = [...];

But Matlab does not allow me to do this.

I know one can use A(:,:,1) = [ ... ] but this is ugly and makes me type :,:, all the time... so I want to know if there is a different solution.

I tried A.1 but structs field names need to be strings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use cell array's:

```
A = cell(N, 1);

A{1} = [ 1 0; 1 1 ];
A{2} = [ 0 1; 1 1 ];
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use an array of structs.

```
A(1).mat = [1 0; 1 1];
A(2).mat = [0 0; 1 1];
...
A(n)...
```

or a cell array

```
A{1} = [1 0; 1 1];
A{2} = [0 1; 1 1];
...
A{n}...
```